# I don't get RSS feed values.. I think error in getting Feed values

Tags: android, json

I am new to JSON. Please any one give a sample code for getting JSON Values...
when i click login button, i want to get User Token  valules from Json object..please help me..

here is my code..

Thank you in advanced..

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.btnLogin:
                 txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
                txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);

        String uname = txtUserName.getText().toString();
        String pass = txtPassword.getText().toString();

        if(uname.equals("") || uname == null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(pass.equals("") || pass == null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            boolean validLogin = validateLogin(uname, pass, Loginpage.this);
            if(validLogin){

            }
        }
        break;

    case R.id.btnCancel:
        Intent i = new Intent(Loginpage.this,Loginpage.class);
        startActivity(i);
        //finish();
        break;

    }
}




private boolean validateLogin(String uname, String pass, Loginpage loginpage) {
     System.out.println("UserToken...");
        loginuser();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Loginpage.this, Main.class);

    intent.putExtra("tokenNumber", token);

    startActivity(intent);


    return true;


}

private void loginuser() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/my url link...");

        token = null;
                try {
                        token = json.getString("UserToken");
                } catch (JSONException e) {                
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }    
            System.out.println("UserToken:"+token);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must search the web to get Example.Bye the way Here is a link.[3 minute to json](http://secretgeek.net/json_3mins.asp)
You must also go to this site to make everything clear[Json](http://www.json.org/)